# Change Link & Text based on Click - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

So I am needing some help again with anjularJS (please excuse me that I'm learning), and I have been researching before coming here, but anyways, I am running into an issue with changing links and texts based off what is clicked in the list.

I have a twitch page that I am working on and at the bottom of the page, I have a link to the streamers tip page for is viewers would like to tip the streamer they are watching.

I also want the text to change as well to show what streamer they are currently watching. So basically, when they click a streamer in the list, the link and the text will change.

HTML:

```
    <main ng-app="TwitchApi">
<section ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table width="957" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
<td rowspan="3" valign="top"><div class="menu-box-header" align="left">
            <header>
                            <ul id="mainMenu">
                                <li data-display="allUsers" class="activeMenu">All</li>
                                <li data-display="onlineUsers">Online</li>
                                <li data-display="offlineUsers">Offline</li>
                            </ul><div id="searchMenu"><i id="searchIcon" class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Search Streamers" id="searchBar"/>
                        </div>
                        </header> 
                </div>
                <div class="menu-box" align="left">


                    <ul id="grnstaff">
                        <li ng-repeat="user in profile | filter:searchText" ng-click="changeSrc('cbox','http://www.twitch.tv/' + user.username +'/chat');changeSrc('tbox','http://www.twitch.tv/' + user.username +'/embed');changeSrc('tip','http://www.twitchalerts.com/tip/' + user.username +'');" ng-style="{ 'background-color' : (user.streaming) ? '#ccffcc' : '#EAEAEA' }">
                            <img ng-src="{{user.logo}}" err-src="images/twitch-default.jpg" class="pic"/>
                            <span class="name">{{user.name}}</span>
                            <span class="status"><i class="{{user.status}}"></i></span>
                            <span class="title">{{user.streamTitle}} <i class="{{user.tv}}"></i> {{user.viewers}}</span>
                        </li> 
                    </ul> 

                </div></td>
<td><iframe id="tbox" src="includes/first-load.php" frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' height='450' width='620'></iframe></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><iframe id="cbox" src="includes/chat-load.php" scrolling='no' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' height='300' width='620'></iframe></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" ><div class="menu-box-header" style="width:620px;height: 75px;"><center><br><a href="https://www.twitchalerts.com/tip/' + user.username +'"class="btn" target="_blank">Tip This Streamer!</a><br><br>Selected Streamer: STREAMER NAME
</center>
</div>
</td>
  </tr>
    </section>
    </main>
```

The JS section I placed here: http://pastebin.com/WraGSder

I hope this explains what I'm trying to do fully. Ideally I would like to also do a URL resolve to check the URL for the link to make sure they do have a tipping page, where if they don't have one, then it's redirected to a local 404 page.

I have tried the guide here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

But I wasn't able to get anything to work for me how I wanted it to work so I'm coming here and hoping someone could help me here.

Thanks!

*Edit (Tried as per below):*
Added on click event to the end:

```
ng-click="changeSrc('cbox','http://www.twitch.tv/' + user.username +'/chat');changeSrc('tbox','http://www.twitch.tv/' + user.username +'/embed');vm.changeToTipLink(link);"
```

Added function:

```
// Test function for text/link changing
  function TwitchTipLinkCtrl() {
var vm = $scope.allUsers;

vm.link = obj.username;
vm.changeToTipLink = function(link) {
  vm.link = link;
};
  };
// END
```

And the link:

```
<a href="https://www.twitchalerts.com/tip/{{vm.link}}"class="btn" target="_blank"><b>Tip This Streamer!</b></a><br><br>Selected Streamer: {{vm.link}}</a>
```

Edit 2: Also tried this, which does change the text, but only reconizing the first click made:

```
$scope.text = 'Please Select A Streamer!';
$scope.myText = function() {
  $scope.text = obj.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a plunkr of what I think that you mean [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/JMgtGYnhpY9madpoPgOZ?p=preview). Is this along the right lines? (This uses angular 1.5 beta 2)

```
angular.module('app', []);

(function() {
  angular
    .module('app')
    .component('exampleLink', {
      bindings: {},
      controller: 'ExampleLinkCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      templateUrl: 'example.html'
    });
}());

(function() {
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ExampleLinkCtrl',ExampleLinkCtrl);

  function ExampleLinkCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.links = [
      {
        url: 'http://www.google.co.uk',
        text: 'Google' 
      },
      {
        url: 'http://www.bing.co.uk',
        text: 'Bing' 
      },
      {
        url: 'https://github.com/',
        text: 'GitHub' 
      },
    ];
    vm.link = vm.links[0];

    vm.changeToRandomLink = function(link) {
      vm.link = link;
    };
  }
}());
```

And the `example.html` looks like this:

```
<p ng-repeat="link in vm.links track by $index" ng-click="vm.changeToRandomLink(link)">
  {{$index+1}} - {{link.text}}
</p>

<hr />
<a href="{{vm.link.url}}">Go to {{vm.link.text}}</a>
```

So when you select something from the list it will update the link with the text and the url in the links object.

**EDIT**

I think you don't understand this style of coding for angularjs. I'll explain abit here. When you use `controllerAs` in the definition of a directive or a controller you're essentially saying that the controller will be referred to in the template as "vm".

What this means is that whatever is on $scope (or vm in this case but I'll get to that) can be called via vm.myFunction(). In your case you're trying to call a function that isn't properly actually attached to vm. Consider:

vm should be like this:

```
var vm = this;
// I.e. refer to the controller
```

It shouldn't be 
    var vm = $scope.users;

And a function attached to it (which you have correct)

```
 vm.changeToTipLink = function(link) {
  vm.link = link;
};
```

Now you can call it in your html. Please note that the HTML template now expects ALL functions from that controller to be attached to vm. You cannot do this:

```
function changeSrc(name, url, etc) {}
```

by itself as this isn't attached to vm. If you wanted to call this you'd need something like this:

```
vm.changeSrc = changeSrc;

// Function definition
function changeSrc(name, url, etc) {}
```

And, again, call it in the HTML via `ng-click="vm.changeSrc()"`

**EDIT**

Change the myText function to this:

```
    // Test function for text/link changing
    $scope.text = 'Please Select A Streamer!';
    $scope.myText = function(user) {
      $scope.text = user.name;
    };
```

and the html to this:

```
     ng-click="myText(user);change...."
```

On another note:

This can all be done in AngularJS - why are you using JQuery so much?

- Jquery shouldn't be used inside the controller
- AngularJS ships with a lite version of JQuery which is typically used in the link part of a directive for dom manipulation

Also - you are injecting $http but aren't using it and are using AJAX
(I'm assuming - $.getJSON) to get stuff. Again this can all be done in angular.

Are you trying to rewrite this into Angular? I hope so

Comment: It is along the right lines, yes, but I'm unsure how to get this working with mine.  I tried to get it into mine but it didn't change the text or link. I have the html and JS in the OP.  Added everything like in the example, but it's not changing the text.

Comment: I updated my OP, I hope I'm not making this more difficult than it should be

Comment: @Yumene based on your latest code i'd expect that it wouldn't. See my edit for details

Comment: I think I am still a bit confused (I apologize), but your explanation does help a bit, but I think I'm looking for something a bit simpler for what I'm working on (this seems a bit too complicated, sorry).  I found this bit `$scope.text = 'Please Select A Streamer!';
    $scope.myText = function() {
      $scope.text = obj.name;
    }`  which actually works, but obviously doesn't work to the full extent.  (it's only recognizing the first click). (added this to the OP as well)

Comment: @Yumene I suggest creating a plunkr so I can edit your code

Comment: I don't know how else to pull the twitch information like that.  I'm still new to it. It all works however, I want to eventually get it all in Angular, but at the moment, I just need that one bit.

Comment: I need 2 more points for my vote to show up publicly, but I have upvoted :)